# orderBy filter works only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Trying to sort an array of numbers either in ascending or descending order, by choice of the user.

This is my code -

```
Order by: 
<select ng-model="orderCriteria">
    <option value="false">ASC</option>
    <option value="true">DESC</option>
</select>

<table border="2">
<th>Number</th>

    <tr ng-repeat="num in [1, 5, 3, 6, 45, 20, 7, 2] | filter: query | orderBy:num:orderCriteria">
        <td>{{num}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the page loads, numbers are automatically ordered in an ascending order. 
When I open the drop-down list and pick either DESC or ASC the table changes its order into a descending order (regardless of what I pick).

From that moment it doesn't matter what I have in my selection, the order is stuck on a descending order!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that (a) you do not have any scope issues, e.g. not being able to update the `orderCriteria` because it is defined in a parent scope of the select and (b) that the `orderCriteria` is a *boolean* and not a string taking `'true'`/`'false'` values - they are both coerced to `(boolean) true`.

Comment: As for (a), I don't think it's a scope problem - if I add another table cell with `{{orderCriteria}}` I can see the value that I pick.

As for (b) - I'm not sure how to do that... How can I escape it from treating the value of my selection as a string?

Comment: Try this: "orderBy:num:Boolean(orderCriteria)"

Comment: Either what jlowcs writes; or, if that doesn't work you will have to define the ASC/DESC options programmatically and use `ng-options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to change order direction easily you can simply use `+/-` modifiers:

```
<tr ng-repeat="num in numbers | orderBy: orderCriteria">
    <td>{{num}}</td>
</tr>
```

where `orderCriteria` now becomes:

```
<select ng-model="orderCriteria">
    <option value="+">ASC</option>
    <option value="-">DESC</option>
</select>
```

From [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) documentation about predicate expressions:

> An expression can be optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name). If no property is provided, (e.g. '+') then the array element itself is used to compare where sorting.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/IS4jDKTtlQd6Pg9VSxVU?p=preview

Comment: Why don't I need to add num to the filter, and tell it by what to sort? What if I had list of  JSON objects? How would it know by which property to sort

Comment: Check the answer, I added a little excerpt from documentation. If you don't add anything to filter (or only pass +/-) then array element itself will be used. If you need to sort by property then it should be passed as a string: `orderBy: 'age'` (say array is `[{age: 12}, {age: 43}]`). It can also be `orderBy: '-age'`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the true/false values in the select box are strings which always yield 'true' in the filter expression.

You can try something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="num in [1, 5, 3, 6, 45, 20, 7, 2] | orderBy:num:(orderCriteria == 'true')">
     <td>{{num}}</td>
</tr>
```